# C++\CLI Windows Forms - creating external class

Tags: forms, class, c++-cli

While making a simple windows forms application with VC++ I have a listview containing some files and their info. What I want to do is only show the filename in the list while storing the full filepath. I created an external class to do this:

```
class FileInfoContainer {
    vector<string> filenames;
    vector<int> uncompsize;
    vector<int> compsize;
    int getFileSize(string filepath);
public:
    FileInfoContainer() {};
    void AddItem(string filepath);
    void AddItem(string filepath, int uncompsize, int compsize);
    void AddItem(string filepath, int uncompsize);
    string getItemFilename(int index);
    int getItemCompsize(int index);
    int getItemUncompsize(int index);
};
```

Now back to the automatic code generated by the VS template for this application, I tried to declare an instance of this class so that I can have the file information available anywhere within:

```
public ref class MainForm : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    public:    
        MainForm(void)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

    protected:
        ~MainForm()
        {
            if (components)
            {
                delete components;
            }
        }

    System::Windows::Forms::ListViewItem^ files;        //my addition
    FileInfoContainer compfiles;                        //my addition
    private: System::Windows::Forms::OpenFileDialog^  openFileDialog1;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::SaveFileDialog^  saveFileDialog1;
    ...........
    }
```

This is generated code where I've only added those 2 lines, of which the first works normally while the second gives a *member of managed class can't be non-managed class type* error.
What can I do to go around this issue?

Comment: FileInfoContainer* compfiles;

Comment: This is not C++, nor it is VC++: it is C++/CLI. Please tag correctly.

Comment: @HansPassant this worked thanks